# Rendering image returns Null data

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So, I followed a tutorial on youtube and got a still image render, but after I moved the camera to get a different angle to record an animation, rendering no longer works and just returns a null / blank image.

I am rendering in Cycles.

It's a simple scene, with only a single camera.

- Using 0 on the numpad shows the area framed that I want.
- I've made sure the camera is selected for the scene.
- All items in the scene are rendering (I checked the using the filters for the collection of objects).
- The camera is in the same collection as the rest of the objects.
- All the objects have a surface.

What have I missed?

blend file
[image]

Comment: Have you maybe lost /deleted your bake cache somehow? Are you able to render the still image again although the animation doesn't render, or is it now looking like the animation?

Comment: Have you done any compositing? This once happened to me when I was compositing a scene and I forgot to plug the last output into the image socket of compositer,make sure than didn't happened here

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the reason for the strange behaviour. There must be something wrong in the scene settings, maybe someone can investigate further.

But when I made a new scene, copied all objects from the old scene to the new one, everything rendered fine. Do not try to copy the old scene by using *Full Copy*, in this case the new scene won't render either.

This is just a workaround to help you rendering the animation. Hopefully someone finds a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I went with the workaround as it was the easiest thing to do at this point.  That's working for me.  Might have a look later to see if I can't figure out why it went wrong though.